# Contar celdas vacías de un CSV en Shell

Tags: linux, bash, csv, shell, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo CSV con 16 variables del que me interesaría contar los valores faltantes de las columnas. Muestro las primeras filas del archivo:

```
2009-01-09,,,0,,,,700.0,0.0,14,1.0,,,,3010,14
2009-01-10,,,0,,,,3050.0,0.0,61,1.0,,,,13129,61
2009-01-11,,,0,,,,4650.0,0.0,93,1.0,,,,20033,93
2009-01-12,,,7,,,,4700.0,0.0,102,1.0,5,,0.0,22031,94
2009-01-13,,,0,,,,6150.0,0.0,123,1.0,,,,26527,123
2009-01-14,,,1,,,,6450.0,0.0,133,1.0,0,,0.0,28276,129
2009-01-15,,,8,,,,6300.0,0.0,140,1.0,6,,0.0,30061,126
2009-01-16,,,2,,,,5400.0,0.0,114,1.0,0,,0.0,23854,108
2009-01-17,,,0,,,,5450.0,0.0,109,1.0,,,,23528,109
```

Prácticamente todas las referencias que he encontrado por internet han sido para contar las líneas de un archivo, pero no sus datos faltantes.

¿Habría alguna manera de contar esas celdas donde hay valores nulos?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿qué intentaste?

Comment: Lo intenté mediante comandos como `cut, sort, uniq, wc -l` e incluso estuve buscando cómo podría utilizar `sed` o `awk`, pero no tuve mucha suerte.

Comment: vale, bien. Digo porque en cada pregunta se recomienda mostrar qué se intentó para no transitar por esos mismos caminos o para ayudar a desencallar

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' tienes razón, lo que pasa es que tampoco utilicé ningún código que me encaminase a la solución, sino que estuve probando varias combinaciones de comandos, con lo cual no quería comenzar a poner todos los códigos diferentes en los intentos que había realizado. Pero sí, la próxima vez pondré por lo menos los comandos que he utilizado, aunque sea por separado, para dar una idea de lo que he intentado. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con `awk`.

Supon que tenemos este archivo:

```
$ cat - > archivo << __eof
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
,1,2,,,5,
0,1,2,,,5,
0,1,2,,,5,6
__eof
```

Entonces podemos ejecutar un program-text en `awk`:

```
$ awk -F , '{
    vacios=0
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == "") vacios++
    printf "Renglon: %s. Vacios: %s\n", NR, vacios}' archivo
```

Y nos da:

```
Renglon: 1. Vacios: 0
Renglon: 2. Vacios: 4
Renglon: 3. Vacios: 3
Renglon: 4. Vacios: 2
```

En este script, por cada renglón, revisamos cada campo en busca de campos vacíos. Con `-F ,`, hacemos que cada campo sea definido por comas.

Otra opción puede ser con `grep`, que, aunque no cuenta los campos vaciós, sólo los muestra:

```
$ grep -E '(^|,)(,|$)' archivo --color
```

No tiene caso poner la salida aquí porque se necesita del color puesto por `grep` con el parámetro `--color`.

En este one-liner, tan sólo se muestran los renglones completos pero con los campos vacíos entre comas de color rojo (sería bueno preguntar si sólo se puede tener este color con `grep`).

Otra opción que se me ocurre y que me parece un tanto ineficiente (y por eso la pongo al último), es algo de este estilo:

```
$ xargs -I % -n1 bash -c "echo % | grep -oE '(^|,)(,|$)' | wc -l " < archivo | xargs -I % bash -c '[ % -ne 0 ] && expr % + 1 || echo %'
```

Cuya salida es:

```
0 
4 
3 
2
```

En este caso, cada renglón generará una salida.

Comment: Muchas gracias! He probado con `awk`y me ha servido. Probaré con el resto también! Saludos!

Comment: Ya por último Cuauhtli, habría alguna forma de hacer la sumatoria de los valores faltantes? Gracias por tus aportes!

Comment: Si te refieres, a todos los valores faltantes en todo el archivo. Podrías poner una variable que sea la suma de los "vacios". Y sumar cada variable vacios saliendo del ciclo `for`. Luego, en un bloque `END` imprimir esta nueva variable.