# Contar cantidad de columnas de un csv en shell

Tags: linux, shell, awk

Tengo un archivo csv que es muy grande. Tiene 6597 filas y muchas más columnas. Necesito saber cuántas columnas exactamente tiene. ¿Como lo puedo hacer?
No he visto ningún comando que me permita hacerlo y leí sobre usar awk pero no sé cómo.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tal vez esta otra pregunta te resulte de ayuda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/410202/contar-celdas-vac%C3%ADas-de-un-csv-en-shell

Comment: @ÓscarNovás definitivamente la respuesta a esa pregunta le va a servir al OP. Buen hallazgo!

Comment: ¿Tienen todas las filas el mismo número de columnas? Ayudaría un pequeño ejemplo si no es así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa el siguiente comando, donde la coma en el comando sed es tu separador (por si no fuera coma).

```
$ head -1 archivo.csv | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c
```

head devuelve el primer renglón, sed elimina todo menos el separador (coma), por medio de expresión regular y wc (word count) cuenta el número de caracteres con el modificador -c.

Obtenido de https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-count-number-of-columns-in-csv-file-using-bash-shell

Comment: Gracias. Me ha servido de maravilla